# Why TickClock out of control when the Duration value more than 60mins

Tags: java, java-8, java-time

First of all, i tried this:

```java
Clock clock = Clock.fixed(Instant.parse("2023-05-04T01:20:20Z"), ZoneId.systemDefault());
Clock tick = Clock.tick(clock, Duration.ofMinutes(3));
System.out.println(clock.instant());
System.out.println(tick.instant());
```

When the duration is 3min, the nearest occurrence of 20min is 18min, it works fine, and print as below:

```
2023-05-04T01:20:20Z
2023-05-04T01:18:00Z
```

When i modify it to `Duration.ofMinutes(61)` by accident, things changed, it print this:

```
2023-05-04T01:20:20Z
2023-05-04T00:40:00Z
```

As API [Class Clock](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Clock.html) says:

> Obtains a clock that returns instants from the specified clock truncated to the nearest occurrence of the specified duration.

So the question is why the result is not `2023-05-04T00:01:00Z` or `2023-05-04T01:01:00Z`? The results are not what it says.

Comment: Truncating to an occurrence of 61 minutes must require some base to measure the 61 minutes from. The docs don’t tell us what that base is. You seem to assume that the base is midnight today in UTC. So maybe it isn’t.

Comment: If in your code I use `Duration.ofDays(100_000)`, I get `1970-01-01T00:00:00Z`. Which is probably the base from which the duration is measured.

Comment: Also confused, the base to measure Duration looks like Irregular to humans, so how can i control the behavior of `TickClock`

Comment: First, the documentation is bad and doesn’t properly specify the behaviour. Second, if you want a clock that ticks every, say, 7 or 61 minutes past midnight in some time zone, you can probably code a clock implementation yourself. Be aware that the clock will skip a different amount of minutes over midnight if your duration doesn’t divide evenly into a day, and be aware that the behaviour will depend in time zone. Are you really wanting to work with such a clock?

Answer (score 1):

This is correct. Given 2023-05-04T01:20:20Z, 2023-05-04T00:40:00Z is indeed the last occurrence of "61 minutes". Specifically, it is the 459880th occurrence since the epoch. The next occurrence is 2023-05-04T01:41:00Z.

You can find this number by finding the number of minutes since the epoch:

```
Instant.parse("2023-05-04T00:40:00Z").getEpochSecond() / 60
```

That evaluates to 28052680. Dividing that by 61 is *exactly* 459880.

See also: the implementation of [`TickClock`](https://github.com/bpupadhyaya/openjdk-8/blob/master/jdk/src/share/classes/java/time/Clock.java#L618) in the openjdk. You can see that it uses `Math.floorMod` to find how much time to substract from the current timestamp (i.e. milliseconds since the epoch). It uses the current timestamp as the dividend.